# What is the default session timeout for a Java EE website?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

If I do not specify the following in my web.xml file:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

What will be my default session timeout? (I am running Tomcat 6.0)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're using Tomcat, it's 30 minutes.  You can read more about it [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=565341&messageID=2788327).

Comment: Unfortunately that link now redirects to the front of the oracle forums. Any idea where it should point to now?

Comment: @Steve Bosman: Might be another link (don't know the other above), but please have a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Session_Statistics. Here you can see, what you have configured in your app.

Answer (score 8):

You can also set this in code, for a specific session using the `HttpSession` [setMaxInactiveInterval](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)) API:

> Specifies the time, in seconds,
>   between client requests before the
>   servlet container will invalidate this
>   session. A negative time indicates the
>   session should never timeout.

I mention this in case you see timeouts that are not 30 minutes, but you didn't specify another value (e.g. another developer on the project used this API).

Another item to note is this timeout may not trigger on the exact second the session is eligible to expire.  The Java EE server may have a polling thread that checks for expired sessions every minute.  I don't have a reference for this, but have seen this behavior in the WebSphere 5.1 era.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure it depends on your container. Tomcat is 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Session Time out we can specify for that particular context in web.xml file as mentined below entry
 
    60

Default Session time out is 30 mins

Comment: Just curious: why are you resurrecting an old question and repeating the already given answers once more?

Comment: @BalusC - Such a good question. Appears to be the only answer.

Comment: @BalusC, @KG: And he registered in SO just to put this answer.