# session timeout automatic

Tags: java, tomcat

I understand that the session timeout is for finding out an idle app and ending that particular session.
I have commented the session-timeout tag in the web.xml. Also I have not set any session timeout in my application anywhere else like maxInactiveInterval().

But my session is expiring nearly after 2 or 3 hours. Is there any automatic session timeout in Tomcat?
I have observed the above phenomenon in both Tomcat 5 & 7. Please help... I don't want a timeout happening for some purpose here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141734/what-is-the-default-session-timeout-for-a-java-ee-website?rq=1

Comment: Default session timeout (one that is used if your web.xml does not specify it) can be set in server.xml, see if Manager element has maxInactiveInterval set. To set sessions to non-expiring, assign a negative value to it (I think). See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/manager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a timeout happening for some purpose:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

should result in no timeout at all -> infinite

Answer (score 1):

yes.In tomcat web.xml file see this code:

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

By default it set to 30 minutes. if you dont want session expiry simply put as 0 instead of 30.

[session statics in tomcat.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Session_Statistics)