# gwt 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable after 20 minutes

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I have a GWT 2.5 application with gxt 2.3.1 with which I made a RPC longer than 30 min. But before I got the response the application pop up a an Error windows With message 503 Service Temporarily message with all the usual details

The server itself in the meantime still processing the data so actually the server is available.

It's realy looks like a session time out but in the web.xml i set up a 1 day long timeout

```
    <!-- one day -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

And after the processing completed I do not got the response on the client side.
So my second guess is the rpc time what I currently currently trying to find out how to set up without success so far.

Comment: `I made a RPC longer than 30 min.` I think its not a good design.

Comment: It means user is inactive for next 30 minutes or most probably user has gone for a coffee. A user session is active whenever there is a request to server from browser.

Comment: Please have a look at [What is the default session timeout for a Java EE website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141734/what-is-the-default-session-timeout-for-a-java-ee-website)

Comment: Most probably there is some other reason of this issue because as per your post's title you are getting 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable after 20 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. As it turns out It's posibble the firewall cancel the request after 20 minute. So the soulution will be to query the server in every minute weather it's finished the processing or not instead of hold the connection between the client and the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GWT Timer](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html) to keep connection active  between server and client by just calling a RPC after an interval. RPC will do nothing other than keeping connection active.

You can cancel the timer once the long running task is completed or you can start it again before starting any task that takes more time.

Sample:

```
// Create a new timer that calls RPC that does nothing.
Timer t = new Timer() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //RPC Call 
  }
};

// Schedule the timer to run once in 5 seconds.
t.schedule(5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as it turnes out its never a good idea to keep the connection alive that much time. instead I should use the timer to ping the server weather it's finished with the task and if yes query the result.

Comment: By the way its not a Database connection. It's just a ping to server to say hi only. Now you can design it as per your requirement.

Comment: Just start the timer when the task is started and stop it once task is finished. Do in the same manner for next task.